# Convert mixed of flat index and simple index to simple column names

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am trying to convert mixed of simple index and flat index to simple column names

```py
index = pd.Index([                 'id',
                                'gender',
                                   'age',
                      ('var', 'mask', 3),
                      ('var', 'mask', 4),
                      ('var', 'mask', 1),])
```

expected:

```py
index = ['id', 'gender', 'age', 'var_mask_3', 'var_mask_4', 'var_mask_1']
```

I try `[ '_'.join(str(x)) for x in index ]`but got :

```py
'i_d',
 'g_e_n_d_e_r',
 'a_g_e',
 "(_'_v_a_r_'_,_ _'_m_a_s_k_'_,_ _3_)",
 "(_'_v_a_r_'_,_ _'_m_a_s_k_'_,_ _4_)",
 "(_'_v_a_r_'_,_ _'_m_e_a_n_'_,_ _1_)"]
```

and if it try `[ '_'.join(x) for x in index ]`, I got the error `TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: Why does `'id'` lose the underscore?

Comment: @timgeb looks like a manually typed example, there are other discrepancies (`subject_id`, `postassium`…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional map:

```
index.map(lambda t: '_'.join(str(x) for x in t) if isinstance(t, tuple) else t)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
['_'.join(str(x) for x in t) if isinstance(t, tuple) else t for t in index]
```

output:

```
Index(['_id', 'gender', 'age', 'var_mask_3', 'var_mask_4', 'var_mask_1'],
      dtype='object')
```